# Angular Material Table: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http-post

I'm working with angular material table, and im not able to populate the grid yet due to below error:

> Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

**search.service.ts**

```
GridSubmittedFilesList: IGridModel;
getFilesSubmitted(data: any): Observable<IGridModel> {
    return this.http.post<IGridModel>(this._url, JSON.stringify(data),
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, withCredentials: true });

  }
```

**component.ts**

```
export class ResultGridComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private searchSubmissionService: SearchSubmissionService) { }

  gridSubmittedFilesList: IGridModel;

  displayedColumns = ['report', 'business', 'location'];

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.searchSubmissionService.searchSource$.subscribe(
      message => {
        this.sendPostReq(message);
      }
    );
  }

  sendPostReq(data: any): any {
    this.searchSubmissionService.getFilesSubmitted(data)
      .subscribe(data => this.gridSubmittedFilesList = data
    );

  }
}
```

**IGridModel.ts**

```
import { Result } from './Result';

export interface IGridModel {
 
    Result: Result
}
```

**Result.ts**

```
export interface Result {
    //grid
    ReportName: string;
    Business: number;
    Location: string;
}
```

**result-grid.component.ts**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 div-expanded" style=" height: 58vh;">

    <!-- [hidden]="dataSource.data.length==0" -->
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="gridSubmittedFilesList" matSort 
           class="schedule-status-table">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="report">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Result.ReportName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
```

I'm not able to realize what I'm doing wrong... I did the same way in order to populate dropdownLists and no issues, but with this Material grid it is not possible.. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the declaration for this.gridSubmittedFilesList in ResultGridComponent ; where is that part? Also here's a link that may help... https://dev.to/jwp/angular-material-table-in-20-minutes-15f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize `gridSubmittedFilesList` as an empty array because it's `null` now or just set `*ngIf` for this table until `gridSubmittedFilesList.length !== 0`